# How to compile C++ project for other plateforms than the one we are developing on

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-2017, cross-platform

I want to target more plateforms than the one I'm developing on it : I'm developing on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 and I want to make my executable Windows 7 compatible (and if Linux is an option, it would be great !).

I have coded a game relying on SDL2 & SDL2image (dll). I give everything needed (dll, files, exe) to a friend who has Windows 7 and it doesn't work. I search for an option in Visual Studio in order to changer target platform, I found it but I can't modify its value.

Here is what my friend has while running on Windows 7 : https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/270873967244476417/386606813308649474/Capture.PNG?width=400&height=152

I would like to have an executable compatible with Windows 7 (and which should be executable from Windows 10 because of its retro-compatibility).

Can you help me please ?

Comment: You want [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). But you need to tell more precisely what does not work. Try to run (on Windows 7) inside some terminal, show the error messages. Edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Might be win 7 32 bits, which won't run 64 bits apps. Not enough info

Comment: I compiled for a relase x86, but I just want to know what is the general procedure to compile for multiple plateforms. Do I have to have multiple virtual machines for example with one OS for each target platform ?